# Laravel - Pass value and key of array to database

Tags: php, laravel

I currently have an issue with a checkout of a website. I need to pass the value and key of arrays to the database, but I dont know how to grab them from the array.

The `$request->toArray()` looks like this:

[image]

The code used to pass it to the database:

```
    foreach ($request->toArray() as $key => $value)
    {

        // dd($request->toArray());
        
        $ordered_ticket = new OrderedTickets();
        $ordered_ticket->checkout_id = $uuid;
        ordered_ticket->ticket_id =  // should be the key of the array
        $ordered_ticket->amount =  // should be the value of the array
        $ordered_ticket->price = 100;
        $ordered_ticket->save();
            
    }
```

Comment: `foreach($request->input('ticket') as $key => $value)`; you're looping `$request->toArray()`, which would have everything (`ticket`, `token`, `course_id`, etc) as `$key`, and `[1 => 2, 2 => 0]`, `'...XbX8'` and `1` as `$value`. Hint: You might need a nested array here (or might not; depends on how many `OrderedTickets()` model instances you're expecting to create)

Answer (score 2):

Iterate over the nested array like this

```
foreach ($request->toArray() as $key => $value)
{
    
    if($key === 'ticket'){
       foreach($value as $ticketId => $ticketValue)
            $ordered_ticket = new OrderedTickets();
            $ordered_ticket->checkout_id = $uuid;
            $ordered_ticket->ticket_id = $ticketId; // should be the key of the array
            $ordered_ticket->amount = $ticketValue; // should be the value of the array
            $ordered_ticket->price = 100;
            $ordered_ticket->save();
        }
 }
}
```

Or even more simple:

```
foreach ($request->toArray()['ticket'] as $key => $value)
{
    
            $ordered_ticket = new OrderedTickets();
            $ordered_ticket->checkout_id = $uuid;
            $ordered_ticket->ticket_id = $key; // should be the key of the array
            $ordered_ticket->amount = $value; // should be the value of the array
            $ordered_ticket->price = 100;
            $ordered_ticket->save();

}
```

Comment: You can reduce the loops by using `$request->get('tickets')` instead of iterating through the full request.

Comment: I forgot, Laravel uses the same RequestInterface. Good point.

Comment: Thank you very much @RápliAndrás :) And thank you aynber for the idea for the reduction of the loops! Works now perfectly fine.